# C# Threading Issue in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a web application and in the code behind page, I have a button click event.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimerEvent TE = new TimerEvent();
            TE.TimerEvents();
            Server.Transfer("~/Jobs.aspx");
        }
```

I am having a method call TimerEvents() and it may take 10-15 seconds to get the control back to the server transfer. so I want the server transfer line to be executed simultaneously at the same time of the method call.

I tried threading as in here:

```
    TimerEvent TE = new TimerEvent();
    Thread t = new Thread(TE.TimerEvents);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();           
    Server.Transfer("~/Jobs.aspx");
```

But the transfer is not made, until the method is finished.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: If the method is taking time, then the optimization should be in the method. By creating the thread is not going to make the method return faster. Is it possible to paste the code of the method?

Comment: The method is supposed to poll a folder for any new files (New files will be placed in that folder after processing of the input file I am uploading in that folder), so the processing may take 10-15 seconds which cannot be optimised( It is matlab file and it needs porcessing time). And i cannot make the user wait for 10-15 secons. hence the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This design is not ideal. Even if you get it right, there's a chance you'll run into problems down the road due to the mixing of multi-threading code and the Server.Transfer() call.

There are also issues regarding multi-threading in ASP.NET applications.

I suggest you re-engineer your app so that you have some kind of queue that queues up long-running tasks. You can then then have a service that processes tasks in the queue one by one.

From your web application, you'll now be able to:

1. Queue up the long running TimerEvents task to the external service.
2. Call Server.Transfer()
3. On the new page ("~/Jobs.aspx"), call the external service to pick up your results when you need it.

Comment: I see your point. can you elaborate on the Queue and external service with any references to achieve the same. Thank you

Comment: Actually I started liking the idea you proposed. Any elaboration on this will be very helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: The idea is that the external service will poll a storage location where requests can be placed. Most developers simply use a database table that has a request_id, request_date, status, and request columns. However the same thing can be accomplished by saving XML files to disk, or using MSMQ. The service polls the storage location, processes the request and posts results and then moves on to the next request. The caller at a later time, can check the *results area* (or simply the status column in the DB table) for the result of the request.

Comment: To be frank, I understand what you are trying to say. But I am new to services. Can you provide any references and detailed explanation if possible. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: I can't find any suitable examples online, however you can start by writing a console application that runs as the service. It will run in a tight loop looking for new entries. Since you wrote that Matlab file processor, it should be fairly easy for you to have the console app look for xml files in a designated folder, read the request in the xml file, save results in another folder and delete the source xml. You'd need to call Thread.Sleep(1) when there are no xml files to process to avoid tying up the processor in the tight loop.

Comment: The second page can then look for the result xml in the result folder. It would know that's the result of it's request because they'll have the same name. Once you have this working, you can look into converting the console app to a full fledged windows service. There are two disadvantages to using a file store. Firstly your web app will need permission to read/write to those locations. Secondly, you'd have to make sure to read the result xml only after the service has completed writing. If these are no-shows for you, you should consider using a database instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the process is repeated in a similar fashion often, what you would call an "application event" why not settup a process on a sperate thread from the Global.asax (application) file. You could use the FileWatcher class to monitor the directory and process the files sequentially or by launching another process in its own thread for each file as they arrive, you could persist a status and any results and expose this to the client possibly using an AJAX timed callback.

Remember to handle all exceptions properly in methods called from the Global.asax 
file as they can bring the whole appDomain down.

[Global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

easiest thing to do:
i would just return immediately and say "You're file has been uploaded" but then do a auto refreshing on your 'jobs.aspx' page and show the status for each job as "Processing" until it's "Done"

assuming jobs.aspx is a list of your processing jobs... and that 'auto refresh' isn't too janky :)